# Azure Storage to Azure SQL Server using FunctionApp

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-function-app, webjob

I have one Storage Account on Azure where I get lots of json files from somewhere. I am running an exe on my computer constantly to get the Json File and read the data from json and convert the data into table and upload it on an SQL Server database on azure - **A synchronization process**

I have not worked with WebJob or FunctionApp

I believe this can be done by FunctionApp triggering on blob. I am not sure if I will be able to do the complete process as I do locally on FunctionApp.

Is this the  right decision for this purpose or would you suggest WebJob for this?

Comment: Hello, I want to check if the issue is solved or not.

Comment: I wish to know if I will be able to Connect Azure SQL Server and Drop data from Json to SQL Server using FunctionApp. Not clear about this only.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to achieve this via azure function. But since you already have a .exe can do this, it's more easier to do this if using webjobs(follow the link in the post below to create a webjob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to use azure web jobs, this should be as simple as just uploading a .zip file of your project. You can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles) to create the webjob, and the webjob should work as what you do locally.

If you prefer to use azure function, then you can use [blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp#trigger---example) do the same thing, but you may make some changes as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I wrote WebJob Connecting Azure Storage and SQL Server with Continuous Running Mode.  Its really easy job.